# Reading Esri File Geodatabase (.gdb) from .NET?

Tags: file-geodatabase, open-source-gis, .net, file-geodatabase-api

I have been reading various threads on reading (not writing) an ESRI file geodatabase (.gdb). What I need to do is process a feature class in a geodb and extract the vertices of each feature. I do not need a visual component as this will be just pure processing of data. Looking for an open-source framework I can readily use in my .NET project. So far I have looked at

```
DotSpatial: Libraries work great for shapefiles but currently no ESRI gdb support
MapWindow: Looks like it supports MSSQL, SQLLite, and Postgre geodbs but not ESRI geodbs
QGIS: Does have the capability to read ESRI geodbs but the API is currently only for Python and C++
ArcGIS: Using ArcObjects this is quite easy but would like this available for users that do not require checking out a license
```

None of these have worked for me.

How do I read a feature class from an ESRI file geodatabase purely for processing the records?

Comment: I think this question is too broad for focused Q&A because it seems to be trying to assemble a list of software options for you to investigate.

Comment: What other way is there to ask for recommendations to address the challenge?

Comment: There's the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) and the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not looking for software per se but API I can use to solve the problem.

Comment: For that there is the [File Geodatabase API](https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/tree/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1) which [includes .NET bindings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308284/115).

Comment: GDAL can read ESRI file GDBs.  It also has an optional module for writing to fGDBs.  I've not used it with .NET, though.  Just C, C++ and Python.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26256 suggests that at least one developer is using the File Geodatabase API with .NET.

Comment: Ahhhhh an ESRI wrapper. Let me try that then. Thanks.

Comment: The latest versions of GDAL for C#/VB.net will read a file geodatabase as OGR (part of GDAL) has an optional driver for FileGDB (separate install), available from http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php, you will need to install core components and some optional libs. When you install GDAL open a shell and type OGRINFO --FORMATS for a list of supported vector formats. I have used GDAL/OGR in C#, VB.net, C++ and python and can attest that it works well though documentation/examples for the .net API are a little hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

The ESRI File GDB API at https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api is exactly what I was looking for.